# How can I rotate entire android screen in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am new in react-native, and I wanna to rotate entire screen manually in react-native, is it possible?
Inside application, on click button start screen goes in background with floating buttons and it start recording screen, I wanna to rotate screen manually from floating button which was in background. rotate screen over all application.

I have checked react-native-orientation and react-native-orientation-locker npm modules which works only on particular application screen rotation.

Is it possible in react-native or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to rotate your view based on your requirements. but for this, I think you have to manage it yourself.

You can achieve to by using the transform API.

refer to the official documentation for how to transform the layout.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms